# How can I count the number of occurrences of an element across two columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with columns: "Color", "Size", "Shape", and "Being Sold" to describe various fruits. The "Being Sold" column contains boolean elements that describe whether an Item is being sold.

I ultimately want to create a plot that shows the number of fruits that are being sold for each color.
I can get the list of all unique colors as well as the number of fruits that fall into each color category with these two lines respectively:

```
print(pd.unique(df["Color"]))
print(df["Color"].value_counts())
```

However, I need to add the qualifier "Being Sold = true" so that the second line does not include fruits that aren't being sold. What's the easiest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the dataframe corresponding to only `"Being Sold"` = `True` using the following

```
df[df["Being Sold"]] # or df[df["Being Sold"]=="true"] # if strings
```

Since `"Being Sold"` is Boolean column, you don't need to write `df[df["Being Sold"]==True]`. Although it will work too.

Then, you can simply do whatever operation you want. For ex.

```
df[df["Being Sold"]]["Color"].value_counts()
```